# Using CKEditor to upload images in asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I wanna use CKEditor to upload images in my project, I'm working with ASP.NET MVC5 C# with EF Code First.
I surfed the Internet but I haven't found any results about it.
Any help please ?

Comment: this link may help you [Link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/add-custom-file-upload-in-ckeditor)

Comment: Thanks @pandian_Snkl

Answer (score 0):

You can check the doc [here](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_file_browser_api.html), anyway I will add simple implementation below,
in your controller add some function like this

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> UploadFromEditor(string CKEditorFuncNum, string CKEdito)
    { //Add some code to handle image upload
    }
```

in your view configure the ckeditor to use that action

```
 CKEDITOR.replace("#ckeditorID", {
        filebrowserUploadUrl: '@Url.Action("UploadFromEditor")'
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @munzer . I'll try that

Comment: Please let me know if it works, or if you encountered any issues`